# Amazon SNS Endpoint Enabled False

Tags: swift, amazon-sns, endpoints

I am using Amazon SNS . I am trying to send a manuel notification the system says your notification successfully send. But if i check the phone there is no any notification and also on the Amazon SNS system enabled status turns to false. Waiting for your answers. Thank you
[Check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZXD3.png)